# Can´t align left legend text

Tags: html, css, alignment, legend, fieldset

I am trying to align legend text to left side but when i do that the top border disappear. If i add `width=auto` I get the complete border but the text align to center.

```css
border: 1px solid #395d8b !important;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
-webkit-box-shadow : 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
box-shadow : 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;

}
legend.border-set {
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="border-set">
  <legend class="border-set">Búsqueda</legend>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row justify-content-left">
      <div align="left" class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <small for="csf">Nombre</small>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="csf" aria-describedby="csfhelp">
      </div>
      <div align="left" class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <small for="csv">Descripción</small>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="csv" aria-describedby="csvhelp">
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-sm-offset-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Online" id="Batch" value="Batch">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRad">Normal</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Online" id="Online" value="Online">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Especial</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Online" id="Online" value="Online">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Doc. Design</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Online" id="Online" value="Online">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Activo</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

[with width:auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkOpG.png)

[without width:auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMroW.png)

Comment: Don't use "align=left" in your div tags, this wont work well with the css framework your using. Stick to css.

Comment: did you provide all necessary code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: In addition, `align=left` is obsolete and shouldn't be used at all.